# RxJava Flowable cache to Single deadlock

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive-streams

Below is my code snippet.

I know you are not supposed to block `cachedFlowable` like this, but this is just an example.

It gets stuck at the `blockingGet` line.

If I replace `singleOrError` with `singleElement`, the code will still get stuck. If I replace `singleOrError` with `firstElement`, the code will no longer get stuck.

Can someone please explain to me why this is the case?

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Flowable<Integer> cachedFlowable = Flowable.just(1).cache();
        cachedFlowable
                .doOnNext(i -> {
                    System.out.println("doOnNext " + i);
                    final Integer j = cachedFlowable.singleOrError().blockingGet();
                    System.out.println("after blockingGet " + j);
                })
                .blockingSubscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it deadlocks with `singleX` operator is that such operators wait for a possible 2nd item emission but since you are blocking them, any second item or completion from the main source can't get executed. With `firstX` they only care about the very first item thus unblock almost immediately which allows the source to complete.

So yes, you should not use blocking methods in flows like that but instead use `flatMap` or `concatMap` to do a per item subflow:

```java
var cache = Flowable.just(1).cache();

cache
.doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("doOnNext " + i))
.concatMapSingle(item -> cache.firstOrError())
.doOnNext(j -> System.out.println("after " + j))
.blockingSubscribe();
```